# How to execute insert query with bulk in asp.net using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I want to insert ImageName, ImageData, Description, CategoryId, Price, DeescriptionFilePath into `ImageTable` in SQL Server 2008.

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        string ImageData = Server.MapPath(FileUploadImage.FileName);
        int Category = int.Parse(ddlCategory.Text);
        string ImageTitle = txtImageTitle.Text;
        string Description = txtDescription.Text;
        int Price = int.Parse(txtPrice.Text);
        string DescriptionFilePath = Server.MapPath(FileUploadDescription.FileName);

        //create sqlconnection
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

        //open the connection
        con.Open();

        //create sql command
        SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand();
        cmdInsert.Connection = con;
        cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ImageTable(ImageName ,ImageData, Description, CategoryId, Price, DeescriptionFilePath) Values ('" + ImageTitle + "',(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'" + ImageData + "',SINGLE_BLOB) AS Image),'" + Description + "', '" + Category + "','" + Price + "','" + DescriptionFilePath + "')";

        int rows = cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (rows == 1)
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "Item upload Successfully!";
        }
        else
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "Error in uploading item. Try again!";
        }

        con.Close();
}
```

But `ExecuteNonQuery()` method is occurred error because I use to bulk to store image.

```
cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ImageTable(ImageName ,ImageData, Description, CategoryId, Price, DeescriptionFilePath) Values ('" + ImageTitle + "',(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'" + ImageData + "',SINGLE_BLOB) AS Image),'" + Description + "', '" + Category + "','" + Price + "','" + DescriptionFilePath + "')";
```

So how to execute insert query with bulk in asp.net using c#?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Please correct my code, I can't understand to do that.

Comment: What is the exact error you get? Is it an exception?